# work with emf files at QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How to convert EMF files to shapefile at QGIS? Actually I have EMF file that has been generated from Autocad-Civil3d.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the EMF file to DXF using [Inkspace](http://www.inkscape.org/en/).  Once in DXF format, the EMF file could be opened in QGIS.  You will likely not have any georeferencing and the style will likely be butchered in the process, so all you'll end up with is base geometry.